# How can I use "Expect: 100-continue" header in Twisted Web?

Tags: python, http, twisted, webdav

I've been working with [AkaDAV](http://akadav.sourceforge.net/), a Twisted based WebDAV server, and I'm trying to support the full [litmus](http://www.webdav.org/neon/litmus/) test suite.  I'm currently stuck on the http sub-suite.

Specifically, I can run:

```
$ TESTS=http litmus http://localhost:8080/steder/
-> running `http':
 0. init.................. pass
 1. begin................. pass
 2. expect100............. FAIL (timeout waiting for interim response)
 3. finish................ pass
```

This test basically does the following:

1. Open a socket to the WebDAV server
2. Issue the following PUT:

   PUT /steder/litmus/expect100 HTTP/1.1
   Host: localhost:8080
   Content-Length: 100
   Expect: 100-continue
3. waits for a response `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` response.
4. uploads 100 byte content payload

The confusing thing here is that it looks like this PUT request never makes it to Twisted.  As a sanity check I've confirmed that PUT requests issued through `curl -X PUT ...` work so it seems like there's something special about this testcase.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?  I'm happy to share sourcecode if that helps.

EDIT:

After a little more looking around it appears that this is a known `twisted.web` issue: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4673

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Because this is Twisted issue you'll have much better response rate to this issue on a Twisted specific forum - I believe it is unlikely a "general programmer", which stackoverflow.com is populated with, comes across this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation it's pretty clear how to modify the HTTP protocol implementation to support this use case.  It looks like the official fix will be in Twisted soon but in the meantime I'm using this as a workaround.

Just include this code before you instantiate your `Site` (or `t.w.http.HTTPFactory`):

```
from twisted.web import http


class HTTPChannelWithExpectContinue(http.HTTPChannel):
    def headerReceived(self, line):
        """Just extract the header and handle Expect 100-continue:
        """
        header, data = line.split(':', 1)
        header = header.lower()
        data = data.strip()
        if (self._version=="HTTP/1.1" and
            header == 'expect' and data.lower() == '100-continue'):
            self.transport.write("HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\r\n\r\n")
        return http.HTTPChannel.headerReceived(self, line)


http.HTTPFactory.protocol = HTTPChannelWithExpectContinue
```

I imagine if you needed other modifications at the protocol level you could use this same method to patch them in as well.  It ain't necessarily pretty but it works for me.

Comment: This is a pretty crude way of solving this issue.  The purpose of the `expect continue` is to give the server a chance to refuse a possibly large request before the client has started sending it, saving bandwidth for both parties.  An even better solution might be to call a method on the protocol that could return true or false to indicate that the request should be accepted (with a default that always returns true)